# Determine why WTForms form didn't validate

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I called `form.validate_on_submit()`, but it returned `False`.  How can I find out why the form didn't validate?

Answer (score 7):

For the whole form, `form.errors` contains a map of fields to lists of errors.  If it is not empty, then the form did not validate.  For an individual field, `field.errors` contains a list of errors for that field.  The list is the same as the one in `form.errors`.

`form.validate()` performs validation and populates `errors`.  When using Flask-WTF, `form.validate_on_submit()` performs an additional check that `request.method` is a "submit" method, which mostly means it is not a `GET` request.